# Winston- Logging Stack Errors

Tags: node.js, express, logging, winston

I have logger.js file, and I import logger from it.

Then I do `logger.info(Console.trace());`

Console.Trace already works, but I need to log it- However, this results in an error saying "arguments of type void is not assignable to type "object"

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`Console.trace()` outputs the stack trace to `stderr`, so you can't exactly capture it. Typically the correct way to get a stack trace is to get it with a `new Error()` object.

```
let err = new Error("Error Message")
logger.log("error", "Exception Dump", err)
```

In the above example, there's a few things going on here. When we call the `new Error()` it captures a stack trace for us. Then on the logger call, we're using the `.log()` method. This allow us to declare the log level, provide a message, and then an object that is handled by `util.inspect()` in the resulting log entry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, this isn't outputting a Stack Trace. In Console, this is what I'm getting: [error]:       Exception Dump. Theres a big space between [error] and "Exception Dump", but no stack trace is being outputted in the console.

Comment: How do you have your winston logger(s) setup? You could always try doing a `console.dir(err)` to see if the error object is populating properly. The only other thing I can think of is if you forgot the `new` on the `Error()` construtor